# Clear RichTextBox text through UI Automation?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, vb.net, ui-automation

In C# or VB.NET, I would like to clear the entire text of a read-only **RichTextBox** control that reside in a external WPF application. The control supports text pattern, but not value pattern.

The goal is to prevent this control from appending thousands of new text lines, because at the end I noticed that it has a negative performance impact on the application when there are many, many text lines.

For that reason, and alternatively, interrupting the control redrawing (if that could have any sense in WPF speaking, excuse me, I come from WinForms), or tricking the maximum character limit, it would be fine too (or I think so).

---

I investigated but I don't have idea how could I accomplish this since I think the control does not provide a Win32 window handle, or at least the [AutomationElementInformation.NativeWindowHandle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.automationelement.automationelementinformation.nativewindowhandle?view=netframework-4.7.2) property is zero for this element, and the [Microsoft's UI Inspect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winauto/inspect-objects) application only gives me the win32 window handle for the main window as shown in this report:

```
How found:  Mouse move (1623,896)
    hwnd=0x00000000009A0AFA 32bit class="HwndWrapper[processname.exe;;8b374e83-68a0-46c8-aa8b-c6792d5ff59e]" style=0x16CF0000 ex=0x4Name:   ""
ControlType:    UIA_DocumentControlTypeId (0xC36E)
LocalizedControlType:   "document"
AutomationId:   "rtbLog"
ClassName:  "RichTextBox"
IsControlElement:   true
IsContentElement:   true
IsTextEditPatternAvailable: false
IsTextPatternAvailable: true
IsTextPattern2Available:    false
IsValuePatternAvailable:    false
...
```

...and the typical functions from Win32 API to enumerate windows does not find any child window on the window handle provided by the hWnd wrapper.

Comment: The major problem is that the control is read-only. You can easily get the RTB using UI Automation (you already have the AutomationId, so one step less). But, I really have no idea how to set/clear the FlowDocument text exposed by a WPF RTB if the control is read-only. Even if doesn't have a ValuePattern, you could use the TextPattern (or `TextPattern.DocumentRange`), select all the text and `SendKeys.Send("");` (since it also doesn't support programmatic selection removal, IIRC). I'll think about it.

Comment: @Jimi I appreciate your interest in the first comment. The second, I think it's out of place (it seems a scoff); I have questions that are not asked in stackoverflow community and therefore never answered... if that can say something good about me (for the little contribution in this meaning), and some times are questions that makes people break his head, as per your comment, for example, on which it seems a little bit complicated to figure how to do so (in case of it can be done), and that is always good to train a programmer's brain. I will try using the text pattern. Thanks for comment.

Comment: Do you own the automated WPF app source code?

Comment: @Simon Mourier No, I'm not the owner of the WPF app that I want to automate.

Comment: Have you considered contacting them for support on this issue? The only other way would be to find the assembler call where the code is calling the write function, and jmp past it to the next point in the code flow (basically bypassing the call) and hope some other functionality isn't destroyed in the process.

Comment: The author just doesn't care about users reporting issues. Patching the assembly is not viable for me since I'm not a reverse engineer and the application gets frequently updated. If at the end its not possible to programmatically clear the text then I can live with it, it's fine, thanks for comment!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately I don't believe any version of affecting someone else's program in an already readonly field is going to be easy. But let me field a few ideas to you that could help you get the creative juices flowing.

In my opinion the only ways to realistically solve your issue are:

- Encapsulate the app! Run it from an application you control and getting your Windows handles could be a lot easier. Then proceed with your previous plan. Giving the app a different parent could change the heirarchy of things and cause WIN API to work correctly finding the handles
- Decompile and recompile. .NET decompiles fairly cleanly and it is well supported. temporary solution, but fairly fast and straight forward.
- Bug the developer for a fix until he responds, if you're paying for it, I bet he sees the emails.
- Hack memory management like a beautiful mind programmer. Could be a permanent solution, but very difficult
- This is me reading into your question too much, it sounds like this application appends data somewhere. is it possible to attach timestamps to the data it appends and create a separate application to manage that datasource?
- Run the program in an environment where the slow down is insignificant. This doesn't help if the app is for a client to use, but if its in office that might just be the most straight forward option.

Unfortunately from a standpoint of sound programming, I can only recommend decompiling the .NET assembly and recompiling. This isnt as terrible as it sounds though! .NET assemblies decompile really well! 
I recommend Resharper DotPeek and ILSpy highly!

ILSpy is convenient, free, straight forward and gets the job done. but recomiling is not built in. you'll need to export the decompiled project and compile yourself or with another IDE.

Resharper is highly managed, well updated, and iirc includes an option for recompiling right there in the IDE. could be an effectively permanent solution because it will be pretty easy to decompile and recompile the solution if nothing else is a workable solution.

### UPDATE:

For anyone still looking for answers, there exists a library called [FlaUI](https://github.com/FlaUI/FlaUI).
It is a .NET automation library already encapsulated for use in a .NET application. It builds on top of the existing Windows.UIAutomation Native framework. And even enables a few things that are not in the basic UIAutomation framework. between this and FLAUIInspect tool to view all the available data on most windows, I have found UI Automation much more straight forward through these tools in the last few months.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for this one ([snoopwpf](https://github.com/cplotts/snoopwpf))

> Snoop is the **open source WPF spying utility** created by Pete Blois when
>   he was employed at Microsoft and now maintained by myself Cory Plotts.
>   Over time contributions have been added by several people, most
>   notably: Dan Hanan, Andrei Kashcha, Maciek Rakowski, Bailey Ling, and
>   Bastian Schmidt.
>
> It allows you to spy/browse the visual tree of a running application
>   (without the need for a debugger) ... **and change properties** ...
>   amongst other things.

Comment: I see what you mean. Well, the application is very bugged, the drag and drop functionality literally crashes any WPF application on which I drag it, so I cannot see whether it really has any working/successful functionality implemented in their source-code to change properties of a control. I'll mean, if the app does not work for me and seems inestable, then I think I can't rely on inspecting its source-code to find anything that could be helpful to accomplish my goal. Thanks for answer.

Comment: It is `open source`, that's why in first place I posted my answer so you you can go deeply with the code, anyways you are welcome :)

Comment: I think you had a good point suggesting that repository, however the application (the compiled release from github) does not work for me with any WPF app that I tried, every WPF app crashes when I try to "snoop" it, and knowing this I just can't take the source-code (which is something big/tedious by the way) and start analyzing it in search of something that I don't know at all what I must search for inside, also I can't try to debug the code to make it work in my PC to avoid those crashes because that programming related to UI automation maybe is the author's specialty, but not mine.

Comment: I'm sorry that I can't help you.

Comment: @ElektroStudios: Would it be possible to post the exception details that is causing the crash?